# Selenium data scrape on popup window by python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I will try data scrape a website with *python*. im using *beatifulsoup* and *requests*.

If I click text link, other information is display on popup window. I want to get the data on this popup window.

I must use selenium, but I don't use to know it.

I search, but I don't find about popup windows.

I can click this text link with selenium and  popup windows is open, but I can't get this information opened popup window.

How can get this information on popup windows with *selenium*?

Comment: thanks for answer but my quesiton is different.

Summary :-

1- Click the text link and popup windows is opening
2- Informations are display on popup windows
3-Get this information 
4-And close popup windows

Comment: Bad English is not a problem, but you know, "I" is always uppercase in English.

Comment: I will pay attention. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to switch to the iframe

```
iframe = driver.switch_to.frame
```

then to switch back to the main body.

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: thanks for valuable comment. i try but the popup windows is not open iframe or new tab. i want aska a questions about my problem. can you write e-mail. thank you again.

Comment: Can you show the HTML page?

Comment: i solved my problem. The informations is embeded html code.i found this. thanks for help